# Непонимание некоторых моментов в поиске делителей

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Есть задача:

> Напишите такую программу: пользователем с клавиатуры вводится целое число, а программой отображаются все числа, на которые данное число делится без остатка.

Корректно ли моё решение, есть ли более правильные решения этой задачи?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");

    int value;
    int i = 0;
    cout << "Введите число: "; cin >> value;

    while (true)
    {
        i++;
        if (i%value==0)
        {
            cout << "Делиться без остатка на: " << i << endl;
        }

    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Если вы запускали вашу программу, то заметили что задача решена некорректно. Вы её запускали?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, да запускал, всё же верно выводится, но бесконечно. Или я что-то не понимаю?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");

    int value;
    cout << "Введите число: ";
    cin >> value;

    for (int i = 1; i <= value; ++i)
    {
        if (value % i == 0)
        {
            cout << "number = " << i << endl;
        }
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Условие выхода из цикла - `i <= value`. Делить нужно наоборот: `value % i`. Используйте более удобный `for()`. `++i` предпочтительней.

Comment: служу stackoverflow!

Answer (score 3):

Вашу программу можно значительно ускорить. Она у вас работает линейно по `n`, а можно её переделать так, что время работы будет пропорционально квадратному корню из `n`.

Для этого нужно заметить, что все делители числа `n` состоят из тех же простых чисел, что и само число `n`.

Если `n = (p1^a1)*(p2^a2)*...*(pm^am)`, то каждый из делителей содержит число `p1` в степени от 0 до `a1`, `p2` в степени от 0 до `a2`, и так далее.
Всего делителей числа `n` ровно `(a1+1)(a2+1)...(am+1)` штук.

Алгоритм поиска делителей таков:

1. Разложить число `n` на простые сомножители, эта операция потребует не более `sqrt(n)` действий.
2. Перебрать все сочетания простых делителей с учётом их степеней. Эта операция потребует порядка `(a1+1)(a2+1)...(am+1)` действий - пренебрежимо мало по сравнению с квадратным корнем.

Программу сможете написать?

**UPDATE**

По просьбе топик-стартера прикладываю программу. Я поленился считывать число из `stdin`, раскладываемое число захардкожено в `main`-е.

Программа печатает разложение 64-х битного числа на простые множители и список делителей. В примере четыре числа:

- 232848, 120 делителей
- 45196767, 60 делителей
- 2097695047, 12 делителей,
- 2147483647, 2 делителя, большое простое число, самое большое простое 31-битное число.

Кроме того, если раскомментировать в main проверку для 18446744073709551557 (максимальное простое 64-х битное число), можно узнать максимально возможное время работы программы на вашем процессоре.

У меня на core-i7 с максимальное оптимизацией работает в худшем случае 11 секунд. Если заменить брут-форс тест простоты на что-нибудь более эффективное, то можно свести время работы вообще к нулю.

```
232848 == 1 * 2^4 * 3^3 * 7^2 * 11^1
1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 3, 6, 12, 24, 48, 9, 18, 36, 72, 144, 27, 54, 108, 216, 432, 7, 14, 28, 56, 112, 21, 42, 84, 168, 336, 63, 126, 252, 504, 1008, 189, 378, 756, 1512, 3024, 49, 98, 196, 392, 784, 147, 294, 588, 1176, 2352, 441, 882, 1764, 3528, 7056, 1323, 2646, 5292, 10584, 21168, 11, 22, 44, 88, 176, 33, 66, 132, 264, 528, 99, 198, 396, 792, 1584, 297, 594, 1188, 2376, 4752, 77, 154, 308, 616, 1232, 231, 462, 924, 1848, 3696, 693, 1386, 2772, 5544, 11088, 2079, 4158, 8316, 16632, 33264, 539, 1078, 2156, 4312, 8624, 1617, 3234, 6468, 12936, 25872, 4851, 9702, 19404, 38808, 77616, 14553, 29106, 58212, 116424, 232848,

45196767 == 1 * 3^2 * 7^3 * 11^4
1, 3, 9, 7, 21, 63, 49, 147, 441, 343, 1029, 3087, 11, 33, 99, 77, 231, 693, 539, 1617, 4851, 3773, 11319, 33957, 121, 363, 1089, 847, 2541, 7623, 5929, 17787, 53361, 41503, 124509, 373527, 1331, 3993, 11979, 9317, 27951, 83853, 65219, 195657, 586971, 456533, 1369599, 4108797, 14641, 43923, 131769, 102487, 307461, 922383, 717409, 2152227, 6456681, 5021863, 15065589, 45196767,

2097695047 == 1 * 7^3 * 2473^2
1, 7, 49, 343, 2473, 17311, 121177, 848239, 6115729, 42810103, 299670721, 2097695047,

2147483647 == 1 * 2147483647^1
1, 2147483647,
```

Экстремальный случай:

```
18446744073709551557 == 1 * 18446744073709551557^1
1, 18446744073709551557,

real    0m11.161s
user    0m11.047s
sys     0m0.031s
```

```cpp
#include <stdint.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Типы 
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Алгоритм работает даже для 64-х битных беззнаковых целых.
// В худшем случае 2^64 - 57 обрабатывает на core i7 за 11 секунд (с включенной оптимизацией).
typedef uint64_t number_t;

// Простой делитель и его степень
class factor_t {
    public:
        number_t prime;
        int degree;

        factor_t(number_t prime, int degree) : prime(prime), degree(degree) {}
};
// Разложения числа в произведение простых делителей
typedef vector<factor_t> factorization_t;
// Список делителей числа
typedef vector<number_t> divisor_list_t;

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Разложение на множители 
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Разложить число на простые делители
factorization_t factorize(number_t n);
// Построить список всех делителей из заданного разложения.
divisor_list_t build(factorization_t factorization);

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Тестовый пример 
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

void do_it(number_t n) {
    // Разложим число на простые делители
    factorization_t factors = factorize(n);
    // Напечатаем получившееся разложение
    cout << n << " == 1";
    for (factorization_t::const_iterator f = factors.begin(); f != factors.end(); f++) {
        cout << " * " << (*f).prime << "^" << (*f).degree;
    }
    cout << endl;

    // Составим список делителей
    divisor_list_t divisors = build(factors);
    // распечатаем список делителей
    for (divisor_list_t::const_iterator p_div = divisors.begin(); p_div != divisors.end(); p_div++) {
        cout << *p_div << ", ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main() {
    // Много делителей
    do_it(232848); // 2**4 * 3**3 * 7**2 * 11
    cout << endl;
    // Число больше, а делителей меньше
    do_it(45196767); // 3**2 * 7**3 * 11**4
    cout << endl;
    // Пример числа с большим простым делителем
    do_it(2097695047); // 7**3  * 2473**2
    cout << endl;
    // ОЧЕНЬ БОЛЬШОЕ простое число (2^31-1)
    do_it(2147483647UL);
    cout << endl;
    // ГИГАНТСКОЕ простое число (2^64-57)
//    do_it(18446744073709551557ULL);
//    cout << endl;
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Реализация 
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Для ускорения разложения на множители захардкодим список простых чисел менее 1000
const number_t SMALL_PRIMES[] = {
    2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73,
    79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163,
    167, 173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 197, 199, 211, 223, 227, 229, 233, 239, 241, 251,
    257, 263, 269, 271, 277, 281, 283, 293, 307, 311, 313, 317, 331, 337, 347, 349,
    353, 359, 367, 373, 379, 383, 389, 397, 401, 409, 419, 421, 431, 433, 439, 443,
    449, 457, 461, 463, 467, 479, 487, 491, 499, 503, 509, 521, 523, 541, 547, 557,
    563, 569, 571, 577, 587, 593, 599, 601, 607, 613, 617, 619, 631, 641, 643, 647,
    653, 659, 661, 673, 677, 683, 691, 701, 709, 719, 727, 733, 739, 743, 751, 757,
    761, 769, 773, 787, 797, 809, 811, 821, 823, 827, 829, 839, 853, 857, 859, 863,
    877, 881, 883, 887, 907, 911, 919, 929, 937, 941, 947, 953, 967, 971, 977, 983,
    991, 997
};

// Первое простое число, не попавшее в список выше.
const number_t FIRST_NOT_SO_SMALL_PRIME = 1009;

// Вместо того, чтобы извлекать квадратные корни из чисел, будем сравнивать их с 
// квадратами простых чисел. Трюк работает для чисел меньших миллиона.
const number_t SMALL_PRIME_SQUARES[] = {
    4, 9, 25, 49, 121, 169, 289, 361, 529, 841, 961, 1369, 1681, 1849, 2209, 2809,
    3481, 3721, 4489, 5041, 5329, 6241, 6889, 7921, 9409, 10201, 10609, 11449,
    11881, 12769, 16129, 17161, 18769, 19321, 22201, 22801, 24649, 26569, 27889,
    29929, 32041, 32761, 36481, 37249, 38809, 39601, 44521, 49729, 51529, 52441,
    54289, 57121, 58081, 63001, 66049, 69169, 72361, 73441, 76729, 78961, 80089,
    85849, 94249, 96721, 97969, 100489, 109561, 113569, 120409, 121801, 124609,
    128881, 134689, 139129, 143641, 146689, 151321, 157609, 160801, 167281, 175561,
    177241, 185761, 187489, 192721, 196249, 201601, 208849, 212521, 214369, 218089,
    229441, 237169, 241081, 249001, 253009, 259081, 271441, 273529, 292681, 299209,
    310249, 316969, 323761, 326041, 332929, 344569, 351649, 358801, 361201, 368449,
    375769, 380689, 383161, 398161, 410881, 413449, 418609, 426409, 434281, 436921,
    452929, 458329, 466489, 477481, 491401, 502681, 516961, 528529, 537289, 546121,
    552049, 564001, 573049, 579121, 591361, 597529, 619369, 635209, 654481, 657721,
    674041, 677329, 683929, 687241, 703921, 727609, 734449, 737881, 744769, 769129,
    776161, 779689, 786769, 822649, 829921, 844561, 863041, 877969, 885481, 896809,
    908209, 935089, 942841, 954529, 966289, 982081, 994009
};

const size_t SMALL_PRIMES_NUM = sizeof(SMALL_PRIMES)/sizeof(SMALL_PRIMES[0]);

// Есть ли у числа простой делитель меньше тысячи?
// Для чисел меньших миллиона быстро проверяет простоту. 
number_t find_small_divisor(number_t n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < SMALL_PRIMES_NUM; i++) {
        if (n < SMALL_PRIME_SQUARES[i]) {
            // n меньше миллиона и не имеет малых простых делителей.
            // Значит n - простое.
            return n;
        }
        number_t rem = n % SMALL_PRIMES[i];
        if (rem == 0) {
            // Нашли простой делитель
            return SMALL_PRIMES[i];
        }
    }
    // Небольшие делители не найдены
    return 0;
}

// Найти простой делитель числа
number_t find_prime_divisor(number_t n) {
    // сначала ищем маленький делитель
    number_t p = find_small_divisor(n);
    if (p > 0) {
        // нашли!
        return p;
    }
    // Тупо перебираем нечетные числа начиная с первого "не столь маленького" простого числа 1009
    // Квадратный корень извлекаем из n+1, чтобы не рисковать ошибкой округления.
    number_t lim = number_t(sqrt(n+1));

    for (number_t i = FIRST_NOT_SO_SMALL_PRIME; i <= lim; i+=2) {
        
        // Отбрасываем кандидаты, кратные 3-м
        // Этого достаточно. Проверка делимости на 5 и 7 не даёт прироста скорости.
        if (i%3) {
            if (0 == n%i) {
                // число i не нужно проверять на простоту. Если бы у него были делители,
                // мы бы их нашли на одном и предыдущих шагов.
                return i;
            }
        }
    }
    // Не нашли. Значит, число простое.
    return n;
}

// Найти степень простого числа в разложении на простые множители.
// Внимание! После выполнения функции число n уменьшается: n -> n/p**degree
int prime_degree(number_t& n, number_t prime) {
    int degree = 0;
    while (0 == n%prime) {
            degree ++;
            n = n/prime;
    }
    return degree;
}

// Разложить число на простые делители
factorization_t factorize(number_t n) {
    factorization_t result;
    while (n>1) {
        number_t prime = find_prime_divisor(n);
        // После вызова функции n уменьшится
        int degree = prime_degree(n, prime);
        if (degree > 0) {
            result.push_back(factor_t(prime, degree));
        }
    }
    return result;
}

// Служебная функция.
// Пробегает по всем делителям из src и умножает их на все степени простого делителя из factor
divisor_list_t update(const divisor_list_t src, const factor_t factor) {
    // Скопируем все делители, не содержащие factor.prime
    divisor_list_t result(src);
    number_t multiplier = 1;
    // В цикле строим все делители, содержащие factor.prime
    // Сначала factor.prime в первой степени
    // Затем factor.prime в квадрате
    // И так далее вплоть до factor.prime в степени factor.degree
    for (int i = 1; i <= factor.degree; i++) {
        multiplier *= factor.prime;
        for (divisor_list_t::const_iterator p_div = src.begin(); p_div != src.end(); p_div++) {
            result.push_back((*p_div)*multiplier);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

// Построить список всех делителей из заданного разложения.
divisor_list_t build(factorization_t factorization) {
    divisor_list_t result;
    // Начинаем список с единицы
    result.push_back(1);
    for (factorization_t::const_iterator p_factor = factorization.begin(); 
            p_factor != factorization.end();
            p_factor ++) {
        // По очереди добавляем каждый из простых делителей в уже найденные делители.
        result = update(result, *p_factor);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: @Вадим добавил реализацию алгоритма.

Comment: большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Конечно нет.

1. Какое из чисел надо делить на какое, чтобы узнать, что оно делится без остатка?
2. А кто из цикла выходить будет? В какой момент делители закончатся?

PS: А ещё было бы удобнее использовать цикл `for`.

Comment: ну, и в заключение -стоит добавить, что перебирать можно до квадратного корня из данного числа

Comment: @Qwertiy Извините, не очень понял первый вопрос, а по поводу второго, ведь не сказано в задании, что есть какое-то ограничение.

Comment: @Вадим, зато в математике сказано.

Comment: @Qwertiy, извините, моё сельское образование и огромный в нём пробел создаёт проблемы и в хобби и в универе. Но, спасибо, что подметили, буду учиться усерднее)